# How to return contents of a List<char>

Tags: c#

```
 public List<char> Columns(String input)
    {
        char[] temp = input.ToCharArray();
        List<char> columns = new List<char>(input.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (other.Contains(temp[i]))
            {
                columns.Add((char)(i+1));
            }
        }
        return columns;
    }
```

My goal here was to have this method return a List. However, when I went to output the contents in another method I got 'System.Collections.Generic.List[char]

```
Console.WriteLine(ex.Columns(line));
```

That was my attempt to output it.

Comment: What do you mean, "I went to output the contents ".  PLease show all the relevant code.

Comment: did u try to print the list using list.ToString()?

Comment: What are you expecting it to print?  Please include an input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's answer the question of why you get `System.Collections.Generic.List[char]`.

The method you are using to output something to the console is [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx). If you go to the linked page you will see many overloads of that method, all taking different kinds of parameters. Let's think which one is being used when you pass an argument of type `List<char>`.

If you look carefully in that list, you will see that there is no overload that takes `List<anything>`. As you know, in .NET every type derives from `System.Object`, or in other words, every type **is a kind of** `System.Object`. When the C# compiler tries to choose a method overload, and it fails to resolve the exact type, it reverts to look for **is a kind of** relationship. In our case, the only overload that matches [is the one that takes `System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx).

So what does this overload do? If you read the description you will easily figure it out.

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the ToString method of value is called to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream.

Okay, so when you pass your list of characters, it will call a ToString() method on it. Let's take a look at the [ToString() method on the `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). When you click on the "ToString" link you will see that you end up on [`System.Object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) page. This means that the List type **doesn't override** the base method. So what does the `Object.ToString()` do?

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns **the fully qualified name** of the type of the Object, as the following example shows.

Mystery solved!

When you write `Console.WriteLine(ex.Columns(line));` the compiler invokes the `Console.WriteLine(Object)` overload which calls `Object.ToString()` on the passed parameter, which prints the fully qualified name of the type.

Armed with this knowledge, you can figure out what to do in order to print the characters themselves. For example you can pass an array of characters to invoke the [`Console.WriteLine(Char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxcchfk6.aspx) overload by writing `Console.WriteLine(ex.Columns(line).ToArray());`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.  A string can always be indexed to get a specific character.

So why introduce a `List` and why have a funky method.  Just do:

```
s[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

No an array would not help you.  To output the contents of a collection you need to loop through each element in the collected.

Using `list.ToString()` calls the `ToString()` on  on `List<T>` which calls the standard object ToString implementation , which is to print out the type's name, which is what you are seeing.

You must iterate over it and access each element instead:

```
foreach(var item in list) {
    string s = item.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(ex.Columns(line).ToArray()));
```